# Is UserDefaults thread safe in Swift? How to check it?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, nsuserdefaults

Is UserDefaults thread safe in Swift? How to check it? For example, if there 10 thread write data with UserDafaults. How we can check that is Thread Safe?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes it is:

> The UserDefaults class is thread-safe.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) from Apples documentation.

Comment: No need to prove it, it´s in Apples official documentation @AlekseiDanilov